Difference of circle buffer area to calculated area in QGIS
When I create a circular buffer around a point feature in QGIS 3.36.3-Maidenhead in EPSG:25832 of a 10 km radius with 1000 segments I get 313961275.193 m² as a result. I calculate the area by typing $area into the field calculator.  But when I calculate it by using
Pi * r^2 = A

i get 314159265.359 m² as the area.
The buffer prompt:

Where does the difference come from?

I suppose you didn't set your measurements to planimetric, or didn't use area($geometry), hence your measurements take the ellipsoid into account.

You need to specify exactly how did you calculate the polygon area in QGIS.

I used area($geometry), but that does not give me analytical result either (as every thing else is just 1, its basically the numbers of Pi and only the position of the punkt changes.
I added a screenshot of the buffer prompt so you can tell how i calculated the buffer.
